# Access ribbon items execute VBA functions

Tags: vba, callback, ribbon, adp

I have some problems configuring my ribbon.

1. Only macros are working as `onAction` or `getPressed` attributes. Functions in standard modules don't work. Callbacks written in standard modules don't work either.
2. How can I use the value of edit box in VBA function?

This is xml of my ribbon for example:

```xml
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="true">
        <tabs>
            <tab idMso="TabHome">
                <group idMso="GroupFont" visible="false" />
            </tab>
            <tab id="CustomTab" label="Клиенты">
                <group id="PeopleGroup" label="Люди">
                    <toggleButton id="ToggleButton1" size="large" label="Все люди"
                      onAction="Pplopenmacro" imageMso="ContactPictureMenu"/>
                    <editBox id="PeopleEditBox"
                             label="Поиск по рег№" 
                             onChange="MyEditBoxCallbackOnChange" />
                    <button id="Button3" label="TEST"
                      size="normal" onAction="=Person_choose()"  />
                </group>
                <group id="CompaniesGroup" label="Компании">
                    <toggleButton id="ToggleButton2" size="large"
                      label="Компании"
                      onAction="Cmpnopenmacro" imageMso="MeetingsWorkspace" />
                </group>
            </tab>
            <tab id="CustomTab2" label="Документы">
                <group id="MyGroup" label="Документы" >
                    <button id="Button1" label="Счета"
                      size="large" onAction="Invoiceopenmacro"
                      imageMso="BusinessFormWizard" />
                    <button id="Button2" label="Хуета" size="normal" />
                </group >
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

And these are my functions in std module:

```vb
Public Sub MyEditBoxCallbackgetText(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef strText)
    ' Callback EditBox

    '  Select Case control.Id
    '      Case "PeopleEditBox"
    '          strText = "Hello World"
    '  End Select

    MsgBox "1"
End Sub

Public Sub MyEditBoxCallbackOnChange(control As IRibbonControl, strText As String)
    ' Callback Editbox: Returnvalue Editbox

    '  Select Case control.Id
    '      Case "PeopleEditBox"
    '              MsgBox "Value Editbox: " & _
    '              strText, vbInformation, "Sample EditBox"
    '  End Select

    MsgBox "2"
End Sub

Public Sub Person_choose()
    'DoCmd.openForm "People", acNormal
     MsgBox "Yahoo!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You may need to tell XML where the procedure can be found.  Example -

```
<group id="PeopleGroup" label="People">
    <toggleButton id="ToggleButton1" size="large"
      label="All People"
      onAction="ThisWorkbook.Pplopenmacro" imageMso="ContactPictureMenu"/>
    <editBox id="PeopleEditBox"
             label="Search by Region #" 
             onChange="ThisWorkbook.MyEditBoxCallbackOnChange" />
    <button id="Button3" label="TEST"
      size="normal" onAction="ThisWorkbook.Person_choose()"  />
</group>
```

`ThisWorkbook.` means that the procedures are found in the `ThisWorkbook` object (see your Project Explorer in the VBA editing window)

I have never put the callbacks into a standard module, but since you are doing that maybe you need to have something like `onAction="MyModuleName.Pplopenmacro"` in the XML?

Comment: Please, don't use Russian, even on the lables from code snippets